# Nextjs v13 API Routes

Tags: typescript, rest, next.js

My problem is that the API response returns a SyntaxError in the JSON response on the front-end. The error that is thrown by the code all the time is
 `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'U', "User not c"... is not valid JSON`

Code:

```
import { getEndpoint } from '@/api/endpoints';
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(request: NextRequest){
    const {username, email, password } = await request.json()
    try {
        const requestRegister = await fetch(getEndpoint('api/v1/auth/signup'), {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }, 
            body: JSON.stringify({username, email, password})
        })
        const responseRegister = await requestRegister.json()
        if(responseRegister.status === 400){
            return new Response(responseRegister.message, {status: 400})
        } else if (responseRegister.status === 200){
            return new Response(responseRegister.message, {status: 200})
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return new Response('Something went wrong', {status: 500})
    }
}
```

I tried changing the new Routes API to the old format, but that also had no effect for me. Currently I don't know what to do. I just want the front-end to be able to read the response well and choose what to do next to response.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like the server is supposed to return a string "User not created".

I also got this from trying to return a string in a response:

`return new Response('response from server', { status: 200 })`

what solved it for me was wrapping the body in **JSON.stringify** so it converts to a JSON string:

`return new Response(JSON.stringify('response from server'), { status: 200 });`

I would also suggest adding the error text to your try/catch:

`` return new Response(JSON.stringify(`Something went wrong ${error}`), { status: 500 }); ``